# Add leading zeros

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a string in the database in the format 01, 0064, 05, but when I preview in *iReport* the leading zeros are not appearing, they appear as follows 1, 64, 5. How to fix it?

Comment: Can you post the *jrxml* file (fields declaration and textField expression)?

Answer (score 0):

In the properties menu under pattern expressions, enter the number of leading zeros you want to appear (i.e. 0000 if you want to see 0064)

Comment: Sir @Raja, how about if the value that will come from database is integer?

Comment: hmmm cast it to a string then left pad? if it's an integer then it won't show leading zeros

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem if it's number like 0009. If it's like 000t then it's displaying correctly as 000t.

IS_DETECT_CELL_TYPE is working fine when the data is 000t but not working incase of 0009.

**You should use "\t" + {field_name} in textfield, to retain leading 0's in excel.**